# Access is denied exception when loading ClickOnce-deployed Excel document-based

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, clickonce

We use ClickOnce to distribute an Excel "code behind document" VSTO customization to users. We send them the ClickOnce publish directory, which they copy to a local drive, then they run the ClickOnce-created setup.exe to install our dll to the ClickOnce cache.

When they click on a button in the worksheet, our dll executes.

On some users' machines, after running setup.exe successfully and opening the worksheet, when they click on the button they get an exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'MyVSTOCustomization,
>   Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToekn=[...]' or one of its
>   dependencies. **Access is denied**." (Emphasis mine.)

We sign the ClickOnce manifest with a certificate issued by COMODO Code Signing CA 2 and sign MyVSTOCustomization.dll with our key.

I'm assuming that an Office or Excel security setting on the affected users' machines is causing this behavior. Have you seen this before? How can I make this deployment work for all of our users?

Comment: Have you checked if this has anything to do with user admin rights?

Comment: @Mihai: do you mean users might need to be admins to run our customization? That doesn't seem right, but I'll do a test and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @Mihai: I created a Standard User account in Windows 7 and confirmed that I could install and run the customization using it, i.e., without admin rights.